# setuid doesn't work in /tmp

Tags: setuid

I wrote a C program, expecting to see the difference between uid and euid with setuid bit enabled:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(void) {
    printf("euid: %d\n", geteuid());
    printf("uid: %d\n", getuid());
    return 0;
}
```

Then I compiled them in my home directory and /tmp directory respectively but got different results. The script I used to compile and run the two programs:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo in current directory
sudo gcc -o a.out a.c
sudo chmod u+s a.out
./a.out

echo 
echo in /tmp
sudo gcc -o /tmp/a.out a.c
sudo chmod u+s /tmp/a.out
/tmp/a.out
```

The result of the executation:

```
in current directory
euid: 0
uid: 1000

in /tmp
euid: 1000
uid: 1000
```

**The setuid bit didn't work in /tmp!** I wonder why.

I `mv` the `/tmp/a.out` to my home directory and the setuid bit worked, so I guess there is something to do with the `/tmp` directory?

Comment: It may be because of the mount options on your `/tmp` - see for example [SUID-bit not working for executables within /tmp directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157314/suid-bit-not-working-for-executables-within-tmp-directory)

Comment: Maybe `/tmp` is mounted with the `nosuid`? `grep /tmp /proc/self/mountinfo` to check.

Comment: @Uncle Billy @steeldriver Thanks! problem solved!  `/tmp` is mounted with `nosuid`.

Comment: This is a pretty standard and perfectly sensible security measure, mind.